# do I need to include @1x images of app only runs on iphone 4s and above?

Tags: ios, image

Is this still necessary? **2x** and **3x** seem to be the only images I need based on models I support. What is the correct approach?

Comment: Is it possible to run your app on iPad 2 which has no retina?

Comment: no. it isnt possible

Comment: it was never necessary unless @2x downscaled version looked ugly

Comment: @brumbrum any iPhone app can be run on an iPad 2. So it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is targeted for iOS9 or less then you still have to build for the iPad 2 which does not have a retina display.

http://www.evad3rs.net/2014/10/ios-9-supported-devices-compatibility.html

Even if you're building an `iPhone` only app they will run on an iPad.

You cannot restrict your app by device. So if you're supporting iOS9 or less (which is every OS version) then you should include @1x images for this reason. If you don't then the @1x devices will just display scaled down versions of the @2x images so you don't NEED to include them... but you should.

What you can do instead (which is something that I have been doing more and more recently) is to use an app like PaintCode. This will take your images and turn them into code. This code is then imported into your project and the images are generated at runtime by the code. They are completely resolution independent and it reduces your app bundle size as you don't have to bundle in any images.

Answer (score 1):

According to [IOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/image-size-and-resolution/) all IOS high resolution devices below IPhone 6, use 2x form of images. So if your app will not run for non-high resolution devices, I am guessing you don't have to add 1x version of images.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing, apple reviewers always test your app on the latest and greatest device. They will certainly test your app on BOTH iPhone and iPad using the latest hardware. They don't have time to regression test your app on every possible device (ipad2, iphone3, iphone4, iphone5 etc). Your users on the other hand will let you know when things don't work as not everyone is on the latest hardware.

Now when you create a project you are required to provide icon images. I am sure you know this screen in Xcode. You can see there are places for 1x images. What happens if you don't provide 1x images? Go ahead, archive the project and try to upload to itunesconnect. You will most likely get a validation error that certain images are missing.

Like other said you cannot restrict your app from running on iPhone 4 Vs iPhone 4s and your binary will be stopped from upload if any required images are missing.

[image]

Comment: Actually you can prevent your app from running on iPhone 4. iPhone 4 does not support iOS 8. If your app does not run on iOS version prior to iOS 8, it will not run on an iPhone 4 or earlier. By default, that is actually the case, because Xcode does not support versions earlier than iOS 8 either.